# Cypress Command never runs, doesn't fail, and returns some meta data instead

Tags: testing, cypress

**DEFINE COMMAND**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getLocalStorage', () => {
  const state = window.localStorage.getItem('state');
  return JSON.parse(state);
});
```

**USE COMMAND**

`const localState = cy.getLocalStorage();`

**RESULT**

localState variable holds this value:

```
chainerId: "chainer6"
firstCall: false
specWindow: Window {parent: global, opener: null, top: global, length: 0, frames: Window, …}
useInitialStack: false
userInvocationStack: " ......"
```

***Using version 5.5.0***

Answer (score 2):

Just use a javascript function

```js
const getLocalStorage = () => {
  const state = window.localStorage.getItem('state');
  return JSON.parse(state);
});

const localState = getLocalStorage();
```

---

Custom commands produce chainers that are for, well, chaining

```js
cy.getLocalStorage().then(state => ...
```

Cypress runs a command queue asynchronously from the javascript in the test. If you want a piece of JS to run synchronously inside the queue, you create a custom command.

Or you can use `.then()` to hook into the command sequence.

---

You are using the wrong `window`. The global window is for the Cypress runner, `cy.state('window')` gets you the window in the iframe, the one the app is using.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getLocalStorage', () => {
  const state = cy.state('window').localStorage.getItem('state');
  return JSON.parse(state);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cypress documentation advises against assigning the return value of Cypress commands (eg. `const localState = cy.getLocalStorage();`)

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values